# Strip value from XML node by locating what the value ends with

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a column in SQL Server that is stored as XML, here is an example:

```
<data>
<pages>4935</pages>
<world_id>88BDBD41-736D-4CF1-4BC9-A6BF4935E481</world_id>
<Url>https://example.com/4935</Url>
<Token>https://example.com/80d71735733e91efc74e71a878eeaee5e84935</Token>
<phone>1122334935</phone>
<email>text4935@gmail.com</email>
<alt_number>334554935</alt_number>
</data>


<data>
<book_id>493567</book_id>
<page_id>88BDBD41-736D-4CF1-4BC9-A6BFE4814935</page_id>
<work_number>1114935</work_number>
</data>
```

The goal is to look through all possible nodes and find the number 4935 but only when it's at the end of its node. If this is located then I want to complete node returned:

The example above should only return the following data:

```
<pages>4935</pages>
<Url>http://example.org/4935</Url>
<Token>http://example.net/80d71735733e91efc74e71a878eeaee5e84935</Token>
<alt_number>334554935</alt_number>
<page_id>88BDBD41-736D-4CF1-4BC9-A6BFE4814935</page_id>
<work_number>1114935</work_number>
```

Here is what I have attempted.

I've taken all the data that contains the number 4935 into a #temp table:

```
SELECT xml_data, xml_id INTO #t
FROM table 
WHERE cast(xml_data as nvarchar(max)) LIKE '%4935%'
```

I altered XML column to be a string:

```
ALTER TABLE #t
ALTER COLUMN xml_data varchar(max);
```

This allows me to manipulate the data as a string. I have used a combination of SUBSTRING, PATINDEX, and LEN to grab what I want but it's not giving me the desired result:

```
SELECT xml_id, 
       xml_data, 
       Substring (xml_data, PATINDEX( '%4935%',xml_data) - 10,  -- Start Position
LEN(xml_data)           -- End Position.
       ) AS stripped 
FROM   #t
```

I'm not sure if my attempt in changing the XML to a string is the best approach so I am open to other functions that can accomplish what I am looking to do.

Thank you in advance for taking the time in answering this question.

Comment: Have you considered using XML query paths to get the nodes instead of treating the XML as a string? https://www.sqlshack.com/for-xml-path-clause-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Charleh does this require knowing all the names of the nodes previously? If so, then it might not work because there is wide variance info and I would need to look through thousands of nodes to map with.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't but there are some limitations in that some functions such as `contains` are not supported. Lookup some articles on SQLXML XPath and you'll get an idea of what's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to stay with the XML data type. *XQuery* and *FLWOR* expression make it relatively easy.

It would be even easier if SQL Server would support the `fn:ends-with()` function. But MS SQL Server is lagging in its w3c *XQuery* standards support.

I recently asked Microsoft to beef up NoSQL functionality in SQL Server.

Please check it out, add your comments, and **vote** for it:

https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data) VALUES
(N'<root>
    <data>
        <pages>4935</pages>
        <world_id>88BDBD41-736D-4CF1-4BC9-A6BF4935E481</world_id>
        <Url>https://example.com/4935</Url>
        <Token>https://example.com/80d71735733e91efc74e71a878eeaee5e84935</Token>
        <phone>1122334935</phone>
        <email>text4935@gmail.com</email>
        <alt_number>334554935</alt_number>
    </data>
    <data>
        <book_id>493567</book_id>
        <page_id>88BDBD41-736D-4CF1-4BC9-A6BFE4814935</page_id>
        <work_number>1114935</work_number>
    </data>
</root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @searchFor VARCHAR(20) = '4935';
DECLARE @searchForLength INT = (LEN(@searchFor) - 1);

SELECT ID, xml_data.query('
        for $x in /root/data/*
        let $len := string-length(string($x/text()[1]))
        return $x[substring($x/text()[1], $len - sql:variable("@searchForLength"), $len) eq sql:variable("@searchFor")]
    ')
FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
<pages>4935</pages>
<Url>https://example.com/4935</Url>
<Token>https://example.com/80d71735733e91efc74e71a878eeaee5e84935</Token>
<phone>1122334935</phone>
<alt_number>334554935</alt_number>
<page_id>88BDBD41-736D-4CF1-4BC9-A6BFE4814935</page_id>
<work_number>1114935</work_number>
```

It is also possible to move *XPath* predicate to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT ID, xml_data.query('
        for $x in /root/data/*
        let $len := string-length(string($x/text()[1]))
        where substring($x/text()[1], $len - sql:variable("@searchForLength"), $len) eq sql:variable("@searchFor")
        return $x
')
FROM @tbl;
```

> A dream where MS SQL Server fully supports w3c *XQuery* standards

```
SELECT ID, xml_data.query('
    for $x in /root/data/*[ends-with(./text()[1], sql:variable("@searchFor"))]
    return $x
')
FROM @tbl;
```

> To search in any position

```
SELECT ID, xml_data.query('
    for $x in /root/data/*[contains(./text()[1], sql:variable("@searchFor"))]
    return $x
')
FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: thanks for the response there this worked. I am wondering what I should do if it didn't matter if the number is at the end of the node. What if I just want to capture it no matter what position and return its node? What change would I make here?

Comment: @Aldo, I added it to the answer, i.e. search in any position. Please don't forget and **vote** for the suggestion.

Comment: Voting now, and TY!

Comment: @Aldo. Thanks. Please ask your friends and colleagues to up-vote the suggestion too.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky The link to up-vote your suggestion did not work for me, but I found it here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0